# std::transform behaviour along with back_inserter not understanding

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a trouble in understanding the behaviour of transform function if used with back_inserter.

```
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a{1,2,4};
    transform(begin(a), end(a), back_inserter(a), [](auto e){ cout << e << "-" ;
                                                             return e;});
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I get the output as 1-0-4. I am not able to understand how this 0 is coming?
Please see live example [cpp.sh/6vpzk](http://cpp.sh/6vpzk)

Answer (score 0):

This code does `vector::push_back` while iterating over it using its iterators. `vector::push_back` invalidates all existing iterators causing undefined behaviour, and that is where that `0` comes from (it can be any other number, since the behaviour is undefined).

You should probably use `for_each` or range for loop.

Comment: But why it prints correct content when I do begin(a) instead of push_back(a)

Comment: @RoshanMehta Because changing elements of a vector doesn't invalidate vector's iterators.

Comment: Ok, but with back_inserter() I am also getting an iterator which points at the end of the vector and with begin() I am also getting an iterator, although this time at the front. How getting an iterator is affects, I do not get it.

Comment: @RoshanMehta `vector::push_back` invalidates begin and end iterators you passed to `transform`.

Comment: if I do a.reserve(6) and then insert element 1,2,4 and use back_inserter, I get the correct behaviour, is it because the vector size is not changing?

Comment: @RoshanMehta That's because **capacity** doesn't change.

Comment: Funny observation: Even if I don't do a.reserver but use a.psuh_back to insert an element at first instead of vector<int> a{1,2,4}, I get the correct result.

Comment: @RoshanMehta That's because `push_back` uses a growth factor and that ends up allocating more elements than 1.